# Can't create object in PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I try to create object in dependence of variable. Here is my code:

```
$a = 'Test';
$o = new $a();

Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in ...
```

What I am doing wrong?  Or in PHP this isn't allowed?

Comment: Is the file with `class Test` loaded? Do you have an autoloader set up? You can easily create classes through dynamic strings like this. The problem is that the class isn't found - not that the code isn't working.

Comment: yes i have autoloader if i write new Test() it works.

Comment: What does your autoloader look like? This should work fine. Does `if (class_exists($a, true)) $o = new $a();` make a difference? (this would FORCE the autoloader to work).

Comment: i use composer autoloader

Comment: I see that you use namespaces - you need to use the *full* class name (with namespaces) and not just the class in which namespace you're currently in. If you're extra lazy `__NAMESPACE__` could be a useful constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using namespaces for your class, you **must** explicitly write it out with your string.

```
$a = '\namespace\Test';
$o = new $a();
```

Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) for specifics.

As h2ooooooo has pointed out, you could potentially use constants to point to the current namespace, `__NAMESPACE__`. Such as, `$a = '\' . __NAMESPACE . '\';`.

Comment: `$a = '\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Test';` could also work and then you (technically) won't have to specify the namespace. +1.

Comment: thanks it help. and another related question, how I can call method by something like this `action . $a . ();` or i cant do that?

Comment: if i do like that i get error Call to undefined function index()

Comment: Assuming `$action` is your method, you can easily do `$a->$action()`, or if action is the name of your method, simply, `$a->action()`.

Comment: or in more advanced cases, `call_user_func(array($a, $action), 'param1', 'param2');`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class Test is not defined...

Try this:

```
$a = 'Test';
$o = new $a();
var_dump($o);

class Test {}
```

Comment: I use namespacec and get this class from another directory. If i write new Test(); it works fine.

Comment: Check if the Test class is loaded ( use \YourNamespace\Test) or you can load the class manual (require ....Test.php). Check if you have the correct names (directory - namespace, filename - classname). Try to verify why autoloading is not working correctly.

Comment: class loaded by composer autoload and i use namespaces

Comment: The response of "Dave Chen" will solve your problem. prefix your $a variable with the namaspace of Test class. $a = '\TESTNAMESPACE\' . 'Test'.